# Modelica annotation inverse of function is ignored

Tags: annotations, modelica, inverse, dymola, openmodelica

***Problem: the `inverse` annotation of a function is ignored and the inverse is computed numerically.***

According to [Modelica Specifications](https://www.modelica.org/documents) it is possible to specify an inverse of a given function.

In order to test this functionallity I tried with a very trivial model with two functions:

- the *direct* function **y(x) = sin(x)**

  ```
  function y_from_x
    input Real x;
    output Real y;
  algorithm
    y:=sin(x);
    annotation(inverse(x = x_from_y(y)));
  end y_from_x;
  ```
- its *inverse* function **x(y) = asin(y)**

  ```
  function x_from_y
    input Real y;
    output Real x;
  algorithm
    x:=asin(y);
  end x_from_y;
  ```
- a couple of releveant equations

  ```
  y = time;
  y = y_from_x(x);
  ```

As you may see, in order to retrieve the value of variable **x**, the function **y_from_x** should be *inverted*; consequently, since the `inverse` annotation explicitly tells how to invert the function, I expect **x_from_y** to be called.

No, that's not what happens. Even just at the flattening step the inverse function is discarded and the solution of **y_from_x** is computed numerically with an iteration loop. This happens with both OpenModelica v1.14 and Dymola 2018.

Is this the expected behaviour?
How does this `inverse` annotation should be used?
Is there a way to avoid such inefficient iterative solution?

**Full code**

```
model test_inverse

Real y, x;

function y_from_x
  input Real x;
  output Real y;
algorithm
  y:=sin(x);
  annotation(inverse(x = x_from_y(y)));
end y_from_x;

function x_from_y
  input Real y;
  output Real x;
algorithm
  x:=asin(y);
end x_from_y;


equation
  y = time;
  y = y_from_x(x);
end test_inverse;
```

Comment: As pointed out by Mattis Thorade, this question is now the topic of an open issue on the Modelica specification: https://github.com/modelica/ModelicaSpecification/issues/2942#issuecomment-895826491 Feel welcome to join that discussion so that we can find a portable solution to this problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in Dymola (and likely also in OpenModelica) is that the function is inlined before the inverse is used, but your syntax is correct.

The inlining can be avoided using:

```
function y_from_x
  input Real x;
  output Real y;
algorithm
  y:=sin(x);
  annotation(LateInline=true, inverse(x = x_from_y(y)));
end y_from_x;
```

However, note that Dymola does not numerically invert the sine function - instead it uses the built-in inverse for the sine-function; which is similar to asin.

Comment: Checked with Dymola: it works!
Unfortunately OpenModelica seems to have some issues: even if the _lateInlineFunction_ postOptModules option is active by default, the inverse function is still ignored (or at least I can see that it still tries to evaluate **x**  with iterative approach)

Comment: According to [OpenModelica trac](https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5300) and [OpenModelica forum](https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/2099-why-don-t-work-inverse) the `inverse` annotation is not implemented yet.

Comment: Hans, does that mean inverse annotation should ALWAYS be combined with LateInline?

Comment: @matth It is often unnecessary (as the function cannot be inlined), and I believe tools should be updated to avoid the need for it. (Will verify for next version of Dymola.)

Comment: Is this related to the Dymola flag `Advanced.Translation.DelayInliningForInverseDerivatives = true`?